# Using JQ to specific csv format

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have a json that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "auth": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "userCustomAttributes": [
      {
        "customAttributeName": "Attribute 1",
        "customAttributeValue": "Value 1"
      },
      {
        "customAttributeName": "Attribute 2",
        "customAttributeValue": "Value 2"
      },
      {
        "customAttributeName": "Attribute 3",
        "customAttributeValue": "Value 3"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "auth": 1,
    "status": "Active",
    "userCustomAttributes": [
      {
        "customAttributeName": "Attribute 1",
        "customAttributeValue": "Value 1"
      },
      {
        "customAttributeName": "Attribute 2",
        "customAttributeValue": "Value 2"
      },
      {
        "customAttributeName": "Attribute 3",
        "customAttributeValue": "Value 3"
      },
      {
        "customAttributeName": "Attribute 4",
        "customAttributeValue": "Value 4"
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

I would like to parse this and have a css output that looks something like this:

```
authType, status, attribute 1, attribute 2, attribute 3, attribute 4
"1", "active", "value1", "value2", "value3",""
"1", "active", "value1", "value2", "value3","value 4"
```

The json has over 180k records in the array so it would need to loop through all of them. Some records don't have all the attributes. Some have all 4 yet some only have 1. I am hoping to show a null value in the csv for the records that don't have the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your sample input, the following program, which does not depend on the ordering of the "attribute" keys:

```
jq -r '
["Attribute 1", "Attribute 2", "Attribute 3", "Attribute 4"] as $attributes
# Header row
| ["authType", "status"] 
  + ($attributes | map( (.[:1] | ascii_upcase) + .[1:])),
# Data rows:
  (.[]
   | (INDEX(.userCustomAttributes[]; .customAttributeName)
      | map_values(.customAttributeValue)) as $dict
   | [.auth, .status] + [ $dict[ $attributes[] ] ]
   )
| @csv
'
```

produces the following CSV:

```
"authType","status","Attribute 1","Attribute 2","Attribute 3","Attribute 4"
1,"Active","Value 1","Value 2","Value 3",
1,"Active","Value 1","Value 2","Value 3","Value 4"
```

You can easily modify this to emit a literal string of your choice in place of a JSON null value.

### Explanation

`$dict[ $a[] ]` produces the stream of values:

```
$dict[ $a[0] ]
$dict[ $a[1] ]
...
```

This is used to ensure the columns are produced in the correct order, independently of the ordering or even presence of the keys.